# Slider - Active blur

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I currently have this

[image]

and I want it to look like

[image]

I tried many things which havent worked please help me!

I am using owl Carousel

My CSS:

```
#owl-slider .item{
    padding: 30px 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.customNavigation{
  text-align: center;
}
.customNavigation a{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.image-fade-left {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

.image-fade-right {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="image-fade-right">
    <div class="image-fade-left">
        <div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item">
                <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full Code : http://hastebin.com/hevogeqijo.xml

Thank You!

Comment: Are you sure your rgba values are `rgba(0,0,0,1)` and not `rgba(255,255,255,1)` ? Because `0,0,0` is black, and you're trying to have a white gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this using only one class instead of two by doing this :

```
.image-fade {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

What I did is add more "anchor" points to the gradient, so that it's white in the two borders (`rgba(0,0,0,0)`) and transparent (`rgba(0,0,0,1)`) in the center.

Or, if you want to modify your code at least at possible, try this :

```
.image-fade-left {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
}

.image-fade-right {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Comment: First code output : https://gyazo.com/b35b668788b332bb4d606f71f760bbd0 and the second one doesnt even show up

Comment: @KstreakOG Oops, forgot the orientation. I edited my answer ! Does it work now ?

Comment: But wait can I make it more blurry?

Comment: What do you mean by "more blurry" ? I'm not sure to understand